# Load 2D parameter from parameter server

Tags: ros, c++, getparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a YAML file which successfully loads the following into the server:

```
        joints: [ [name_1_1, name_1_2], 
            [name_2_1, name_2_2], 
            [name_3_1], 
            [name_4_1, name_4_2], 
            [name_5_1, name_5_2], 
            [name_6_1, name_6_2] ]
```

But I am having problems writing the c++ to return the contents.
For a 1D vector I can easily use:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
nh.getParam("/joints", names);
```

where the YAML could be:

```
joints: [name_1, name_2, name_3]
```

To go 2D I tried to load it with:

```
std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > names;
nh.getParam("/joints", names);
```

But I get a build error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::getParam(const char [17], std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >&)’
```

How can I load 2D parameters from the ros parameter server in C++?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214981/load-2d-parameter-from-parameter-server/) by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 327 on 2015-07-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no automatic way to do this.
You have have to write a parser using `XmlRpc` yourself.

See the [ROS documentation on the Paramter Server](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists), the [ROS XmlRpc API](http://docs.ros.org/api/xmlrpcpp/html/classXmlRpc_1_1XmlRpcValue.html), and maybe [this ROS Answers question](http://answers.ros.org/question/212372/get-the-name-of-a-sub-parameter-not-the-whole-structure/#212523) for reference.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6